# Windows Phone: find the VerticalOffset of a button

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

In Windows phone, how do I find the VerticalOffset of a button? I have a ScrollView with a bunch of content. I want to use ScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset to get to a specific point (a button), but don't know how to get the position of that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have both items, you should be able to use `TransformToVisual` to get the location of one control relative to another, then use that to scroll

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.transformtovisual.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is how I get the x and y coordinates of two buttons in my app and move them. Maybe you can do something similar:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(imUp, Canvas.GetLeft(imUp) + offsetX);
Canvas.SetLeft(imDown, Canvas.GetLeft(imDown) + offsetX);
```